# Error connecting to specific WFS layer with QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs

I am trying to connect to the following WFS using QGIS:

> http://mapservices.prorail.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basis_topografie_002/FeatureServer

However this gives me the following QGIS error:

> Capabilities document is not valid
>
> error occurred while parsing reference

I am using QGIS version 2.14

Is my URL wrong? I do get information if I open this in my browser.

Comment: ArcGIS REST is not WFS. Perhaps http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/spoorwegen/wfs?version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities  or similar might help.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found a guide for connecting to ArcGIS rest using a higher version of QGIS. trying that now...

Comment: QGIS 2.18 crashes when I try to open it as ArcGIS FeatureService layer... this is getting so far off-topic I will start a new question

Answer (score 3):

> Is my URL wrong? I do get information if I open this in my browser.

Well your URL isn't the endpoint for a WFS.  You should be able to append the following parameters (`service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&`) and get a GetCapabilities response (an XML document) but you don't, see:

http://mapservices.prorail.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basis_topografie_002/FeatureServer?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&

Comment: Thanks for your answer, turns out this is indeed not a WFS endpoint, but an ArcGIS FeatureServer endpoint. QGIS is still struggling with this

Comment: That's why it's better to use standards